# Silverlight - Style ALL Image Buttons to Change on MouseOver

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0, visualstatemanager

I'm having a really hard time finding a way to do the following...

I have my "Image button style," and it is applied to every button in my **Silverlight** app. Is there any way to make a blanket `VisualStateManager` to change the image on MouseOver, that will work for every button? I have a couple ideas, but I'm not sure if they can be implemented...

Let's say my button image paths are consistent:

- image1.png
- image2.png

and

- image1 - hover.png
- image2 - hover.png

Is there a way to change the path of the image to append " - hover"? I thought about using an IValueConverter for this, but wasn't sure how to access the control state...

An alternative idea I had was if there was a way to accomplish this:

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="../Images/image1.png" Width="70"/>
    <Image Source="../Images/image1 - hover.png" Width="70"/>
</Button>
```

Have two contents (an array of content?) and on Normal state, set only the first content opacity to 1, and the rest to 0. Then on MouseOver, switch the opacities.

Are any of these solutions feasible, and how can they be implemented?

Thanks

---

**Edit:** I know I can make custom styles for each button that switch out their images, but I would like a blanket style that I can apply to all buttons.

Comment: So why not just make your style (except use visibility instead of opacity for less weight) and apply it globally?

Comment: Please clarify. You already have a functioning Style for all your Buttons? But that Style does currently not switch between two images on mouseOver? And you want to know what options you have to make all your Buttons into "two-images-that-are-swapped-onMouseOver"-Buttons?

Comment: @Martin Yes, I am just using a style that only renders the content - the grid/background etc. are transparent, so you just see the Image. Yes, what are my options? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may (ab)use the `Tag` property for your purpose and create a ControlTemplate with two `Image` controls with a `BitmapImage` that binds its `UriSource` property to either the `Content` or the `Tag` property respectively:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="image1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="image2"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Image x:Name="image1">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Content,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                    <Image x:Name="image2" Opacity="0">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Tag,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now you may declare a Button like this:

```
<Button Content="../Images/image1.png" Tag="../Images/image1_hover.png"/>
```

Comment: I did think of something like this... However, for some buttons I am actually using the Tag. Also, I would eventually like to extend this style for three buttons -- normal, hover, and disabled. Can I extend a button to include additional properties?

Comment: You may perhaps use [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265152(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: I went about this by using your method, however I added a converter to convert the Binding value. That way I could get away with just using the Content property (i.e. image) and converted it to: image.png, image - hover.png, image - disabled.png respectively. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To add: I think combining our methods makes this approach much better. I can imagine someone downvoting your solution because of the "abuse" of Tag property, but ultimately that doesn't have to be done. You could edit your answer if you wanted.